# How to install Laravel Passport with no error that is the following one

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am trying to install Passport in Laravel. I follow exactly all the guides and I facing this problem
[image]

I already put in app.php   the follow
[image]

I try to follow advice from here on similar problems but nothing resolving, I try composer dump-autoload. ecc. Any help please?

Comment: follow this https://medium.com/modulr/create-api-authentication-with-passport-of-laravel-5-6-1dc2d400a7f

Comment: Unfortunately giving the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `composer dump-autoload` 
Then run `php artisan serve`

> **composer dump-autoload** won’t download a thing. It just regenerates the list of all `classes` that need to be included in the project
> (`autoload_classmap.php`). Ideal for when you have a new class inside
> your project.

Comment: Nothing to do. I try to install a new fresh Laravel and a restart the procedure with the official documentation for PassPort and when I have php artisan migrate I have serious problems that cannot be anykind of connection because the terminal reject the connection

Comment: Fixed! After reinstalling Laravel i ve done the correct connection with database and everything working! Thanks to everybody for your time!

Answer (score 0):

There are dependencies that Laravel passport requires running the `composer require Laravel/passport` will trigger the error you are facing.

Solution:
Try `composer require Laravel/passport -w` to run the package with its required dependencies instead of uninstalling and re-installing the project.